# If one must retrieve one's checked bag during a layover, is that indicated on the checked bag's tags/stickers?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, layovers

Assume a passenger takes a flight with a layover. They check in a bag, which they are told they must retrieve during their layover. Is the fact that the checked bag must be retrieved during their layover indicated on the checked bag's tags/stickers, or in some other document (e.g., boarding pass)?

Comment: It's certainly NOT on the boarding pass. The bar code on the sticker contains enough information for the automated bag handling system to figure out where the bag needs to go. I don't know whether a pickup requirement is hard coded on the tag or the local system decides on the fly based on the  source and destination info.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on the airport and type of connection. The rule of thumb is:

- International - Domestic connection, you have to recheck.
- Domestic - International, in most cases, no. Just ask at the counter.
- Domestic - Domestic - No
- International - International, For USA and some other countries you need to recheck. For most other countries, no need. Clarify with the counter.

Exceptions - Countries in the Schengen area are considered like one whole country as far as immigration is concerned. So, if you are going like Paris - Berlin - Frankfurt, no need to recheck.

To answer your question, usually, the boarding pass won't have any indication. Also, the above rules apply only for single ticket flights. If you purchased both legs separately, you need to recheck.

Comment: Thanks! Is the fact that the checked bag must be retrieved during their layover indicated on the checked bag's tags/stickers?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I haven't seen one yet. So, not usually.

Comment: Doesn't the airport code in bag tag mean "checked until that airport"?  If the bag tag claims the destination airport, then it will be automatically routed there but if it claims some layover airport, then re-check is required?

Comment: @Athenenoctua Tags don't only list the final airport, but also all layover airports, plus the flight numbers. If they didn't, baggage handlers wouldn't know where to load the bag. I once flew Cape Town - Johannesburg - Frankfurt - Friedrichshafen. If the layover airports were not listed, how should the luggage handlers know, that the bag with "FDH" on the tag has to be loaded on the plane to Johannesburg? Still, my bag was routed all the way to Friedrichshafen, which was the first (and only) airport where I picked it up.

Comment: This answer is only right, if it is at all, for get your luggage, walk it through customs and hand it back in. If you have a longer stop where you get your luggage to use it, like overnight, the airports beyond that stop will not be on the tags.

Comment: @Sabine I believe the question was whether having FDH on the tag means it's checked through to FDH

Comment: @Athenenoctua , yes it means that, **but it does _not_ imply** that you don't need to pick it up and re-check it. The latter happens mainly whenever you enter the US, as not all airports in the US have customs/immigration. So there you always need to get your baggage, present / carry it through customs, and drop it back on the belt.

Comment: @user253751 Athene noctua uses the phrase "claims some layover airport". I understood this to mean "shows a list of airports including some layover airports" and was giving a lengthy and not-well-written counterexample that the mention of an airport on the tag does not necessarily mean one has to handle ones bags there. If this was supposed to mean "lists a layover airport as the last / only airport", I agree that my comment does not get to the point.

Comment: For *luggage* (rather than passport control), what matters in Europe is the EU, not Schengen. Also all international-to-domestic (where “domestic” means intra-EU) connections do not require you to claim/recheck bags, as long as the final airport has customs. You do *not* need to get your luggage through customs at your port of entry into the EU. Bags will eventually be inspected at your final airport. There is an obviously visible difference in baggage tags to manage that.