# Reclaiming Checked Baggage

Tags: schengen, luggage, connecting-flights

Does the location mentioned in baggage receipt that's pasted behind the boarding pass indicate whether you will have to recalim your baggage at that location and NOT at the location where you wait(incase of a connecting flight?

Comment: [If one must retrieve one's checked bag during a layover, is that indicated on the checked bag's tags/stickers?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174351/if-one-must-retrieve-ones-checked-bag-during-a-layover-is-that-indicated-on-th). Also, FYI: [Which countries force all arriving international passengers to claim their luggage for the purpose of customs inspection?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/150841/1810).

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I’m pretty sure people having a connection in the US will have their luggage tagged to the final destination (and that’s what will appear on the receipt, I believe) but still have to claim their luggage at the port of entry in most cases.

Comment: @jcaron Maybe...but without knowing the other factors I listed, not yet knowable on the facts disclosed by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

The baggage receipt is primarily a record locator. In most cases the receipt will list all flights and destination through which the bags will be transported. Obviously you have to claim the bags at the last city listed, which is typically the final stop of you itinerary.

There is typically no additional information about whether you have to claim and recheck somewhere along the way (which normally happens only in the US and Canada). The will tell you at check in and on the plane.

Comment: Re "happens only in the US and Canada": When I travelled to Norway 20 and 13 years ago, they required passengers to claim their bags in Oslo (OSL) for customs, then recheck for their connecting flight. Could anyone clarify whether or not that is still the case?

Comment: No idea. Seems unusual for a Schengen country.

Comment: @Sabine's case can happen when the final destination only serves internal flights, and all customs & immigration formalities are handled at the international airport, even if some travellers may be coming from Schengen countries.

Answer (score 1):

You must pick up your checked baggage at the destination airport as shown on the receipt.

Whether you must pass through Customs at the pick-up airport, or later at a destination airport, depends on a) whether you have one ticket or more than one ticket, and b) the identity of the airline(s), and c) the identity of the airports.

As jacaron notes in comments, the US can be a special case. Whether it is (or not) in your situation depends on the factors listed above.